# How do I rename an .aspx page so the "code behind" page gets renamed appropriately?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I've got an aspx page with a aspx.vb "code behind" page.
I want to rename the .aspx page but that'll "break" the link to the .vb page.

I know I can rename the Inherits, but I thought there might be a more "proper" way to do this  (also it's possible that there might be some references elsewhere)

Answer (score 1):

Rename it in Visual Studio it should automatically update the linked filenames.

If it doesn't rename the class, us Refactor Rename and that will update those in-code references.